# Non-atomical assignement in multi-threaded applications

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Should I always care about atomicity when assigning values in multi-threaded projects? I have two threads running parallel. Can I safely change non-DWORD variable if it is used as flag only? Or do I have to use DWORD aligned variable (or DWORD itself) since Microsoft guarantees that it will be changed atomically? Or do I have to slow down my code and use Interlocked*() functions instead? Will my code still work fine if I go down from 32- to 16-bits system or go up from 32- to 64-bits system?

```
/* real value doesn't matter, only null or not-null */
short flag;
// DWORD flag;

DWORD WINAPI thread_1(LPVOID* param)
{
  while(true){/* do stuff, flag can be changed non-atomically */}
  return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI thread_2(LPVOID* param)
{
  while(true){if(flag){/* do stuff */}}
  return 0;
}
```

**update**

`thread_2` is only observing the flag while `thread_1` changes it.

Comment: No, it is not safe.  You need to use some sort of interlock - critical section, semaphore, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8290768/535275

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks. but why since i don't need an exact value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use use the `Interlocked*` functions or (better yet) C++11 atomics.

Comment: thanks. i made a little update. do i still have to use locks if only one of two threads changes variable while other observes?

Comment: Yes. Anytime you have a write concurrent with anything, you need atomics. (Or use locks to make it not concurrent.)

Comment: what would be better to use: microsoft interlocked functions or c++11 atomics?

Comment: Atomics. They have more clearly defined semantics, making them easier to reason about for both programmers and compilers (which is good for optimization). They're also portable, which may matter to you in the future.